# Mostrar apenas 1 registro de tabela secundária junto com tabela primária em cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um cursor onde me traz dados de um pedido (tabela mãe) e os itens do pedido em xml(tabela filha) atualmente o cursor traz pedido por pedido com o fetch next, porém a tabela filha vem com todos os itens (coluna "teste") e gostaria que viesse item por item. por exemplo:

pedido 1 item 1

pedido 1 item 2

pedido 1 item 3

A ideia é utilizar uma tabela temporária, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. Alguém poderia dar uma luz? Segue imagem do resultado atual e código.

```
DECLARE crs CURSOR
select distinct a.DocEntry
,cardcode,cardname,a.CreateDate,DATEDIFF(day,a.CreateDate,GETDATE()) Dias_Em_Aberto,d.SlpName
,CONCAT(ISNULL(substring((select '/'+ ItemCode from RDR1 where RDR1.DocEntry = a.DocEntry for xml path ('')),2,9999),'')+'  '+substring((select '-'+ CAST(Onhand as varchar(200) )from OITM where OITM.ItemCode = b.ItemCode for xml path ('')),2,9999),'') teste
from ordr a........
```

[image: Cursor]

Comment: Disponibilize o seu XML pra podermos sugerir algo

Comment: o "xml" seria a coluna teste, cada código de item vem separado pela barra, mas queria que fosse uma linha, caso eu tenha entendido errado por favor explique me

Comment: Acho que é melhor você colocar mais umas informações na sua pergunta: 1) A estrutura das tabelas envolvidas. 2) dados de exemplo dessas tabelas. 3) o resultado esperado

Comment: Bom dia!
A estrutura seria meio impossível por que elas são extremamente grandes, são tabelas do SAP B1. Vou adicionar mais dados e também colocar o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá viva partilha mais informação como já sugeriram. Partilho aqui um exemplo simples como criares uma temp table com SQL Server. Partilho também como remover no fim da utilização:

**Create TEMP Table**

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('#ID_Table') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        --IF NULL CREATE TEMP TABLE
        CREATE TABLE #ID_Table
        (
            [ID] INT
        );
    END
```

**Remove TEMP table**

```
--DROP TEMP TABLE IF EXISTS AFTER USAGE
IF(OBJECT_ID('#ID_Table') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #ID_Table
END
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Ernesto!